# Matplotlib years plot as year end

Tags: matplotlib

I have years on the bottom of my chart, like below

[image]

I have daily data and yearly data. The yearly data is reported as year end.

How do I get 1990 turned into 1989-12 ?

I've tried monkey-patching DateFormatter like so:

```
my_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')

def new_caller(self, x, pos=0):
    print('called date formatter')
    d = pd.Timestamp(num2date(x, self.tz)) - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
    return d.strftime(self.fmt)

my_format.__call__ = new_caller

...

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(my_format)
```

This doesn't work, and because I see no `called date formatter` in console, I don't think the date formatter is even being called. If this is the way one would do it, what method actually needs patching to make this work?

Comment: You need to attach the formatter to the axis.  Complete working example might help.  I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve; do you want the tick at 1 Jan 1990 marked as "12-1989"?  Or do you want the tick to be at 1 Dec 1989? Because to me a tick of 12-1989 means 1 Dec 1989.

Comment: Formatter was already attached to the axis. I solved the problem by going at it another way, by setting the locator like so: 
`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(base=2, month=12, day=31)); ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.YearLocator(base=1, month=12, day=31))`

Comment: Great.  Thats why I was asking where you wanted the tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the axes which contain the chart:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(base=2, month=12, day=31))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.YearLocator(base=1, month=12, day=31))
```

Mutatis mutandis for various different bases as necessary and which ticks need moving.

To force formatting as just the year:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
```